# How can I create a table that combines the date for multiple users even if it's null date for that user?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a table that shows the history of every users purchase history. I have one table that shows the date, #DateTable and another table that shows each individual purchase with columns, "UserNumber" and "PurchaseDate" and "Purchaseamount"

How can I join these two together to get the sum of each users Purchaseamount for every single day, even if they don't make a purchase that day?

Comment: include column for first table?

Comment: The columns in the first table are "Date" and then I have them parted out into Year, Month, and Day as integers

Comment: left join? fairy dust? You haven't given us any information to work with here.

Comment: Have you tried to make a query for this yet?  I'd advise showing us how far you got on your own.

Comment: You question is unclear, add enough information with your tried efforts

Comment: Yes, I've tried left joining, but if the user didn't make a purchase on that date it counts as null, so it combines all of the users dates where there is no purchase made as 0 and identifies as a null for the usernumber.

Comment: You do realize that we can't see your screen, we have no idea what your table structures are, we have no idea what you are trying to do??? In short, you have stated that you tried something but it didn't work. There are are least three people that have responded so far, likely all wanting to help. Unfortunately we can't because you haven't provided any information. DDL and sample data would be a great start. sqlfiddle.com would be a good way to post that.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of description, I figured out that I could just use cartesian product and left joining from that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can accomplish this by using only your second table?

```
SELECT UserNumber, 
       PurchaseDate, 
       (CASE 
            WHEN PurchaseAmount IS NULL THEN '0' 
            ELSE SUM(PurchaseAmount) 
        END) PurchaseAmount
FROM PurchaseTable
GROUP BY UserNumber, DAY(PurchaseDate)
```

If the above doesn't work, try modifying to `WHEN SUM(PurchaseAmount) IS NULL...`